# How to assign different type to variable and call a function with it in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations

I’m from python and a newbie to kotlin/java.

I’m wondering how to assign different annotation to variable and call function with it.

```
var metadata = field.getAnnotation(AnnotationA::class.java) ?: field.getAnnotation(AnnotationB::class.java)
if (metadata != null) {
    someFunction(metadata) 
    // which has two overrided functions with AnnotationA and AnnotationB
    // looks like someFunction(AnnotationA)
    //            someFunction(AnnotationB)
}
```

Compiler says “None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.”
and it says metadata is casted to ‘Annotation!’

How can I set AnnotationA or AnnotationB to metadata and use my overrided someFunction according to the type?

Comment: You would have to try to call each function one by one. Functions don't dispatch like that in Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Alternatively, rather than trying to call different functions depending on the annotation, you can consider changing your design completely and write an annotation processor (in Java or Kotlin) that generates code based on annotations.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. I hoped I could make it work with less code like in python. As you said, I made when expression for calling each function by type, and it works well. Making annotation processor would be good approach I think. Thanks for the idea!!

Comment: FYI, it is usually a bad idea to _directly_ translate from one language to another :)

Comment: Agree with you. I got the kotlin syntax and read documentations a few days ago, but in practice it's not that easy for me to transform my design process from python to kotlin.. :)

Comment: Reflection is a fairly advanced topic, and annotation processing definitely so — if you're just starting with Kotlin, it's probably a sign that there's a different, better approach!

Comment: Thanks for your advice gidds :) In this case I choose to use simple when expression. But I'll conquer the Reflection and Annotation things soon. Please rooting for me! 

Comment: But in Python you couldn't have two overloaded functions for `AnnotationA` and `AnnotationB` in the first place. You _could_ have a similar design to Python by making one function which takes an `Annotation` and checks if it's an `AnnotationA` or an `AnnotationB` inside. However, I don't recommend this.